# jQuery Runtime Error: Function Expected

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-5, runtime-error

I am using jQuery UI Autocomplete on my *Create* View in my web application

When I click in the textbox that I want the autocomplete to service, and type 1 letter, I receive a runtime error:

[image: Runtime Error]

Here is the line of the built in script debugger where the error is occurring

[image: line of the built in script debugger where the error is occurring]

Here is my **Script**:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#Categories').autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "/Activities/AutoCompleteCategory",
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                data: { term: request.term },
                success: function (data) {
                    response($.map(data, function (item) {
                        return { label: item.subcategory, value: item.subcategory };
                    }))
                }
            })
        },
        messages: {
            noResults: "", results: ""
        }
    });
})
</script>
```

Here is my **Controller:**

```
public JsonResult AutoCompleteCategory(string term)
{
    var result = (from r in db.Activities
                  where r.subcategory.ToUpper().Contains(term.ToUpper())
                  select new { r.subcategory }).Distinct();

    return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

If I click *Do not show this message again*, it works perfectly.

Any help  to figure out why this run-time error is happening is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code that's failing is trying to execute the results method under messages.

```
this.messages.results(e.length)
```

You have defined the results method as "" here:

```
    messages: {
        noResults: "", results: ""
    }
```

The browser is probably handling this error silently after you cancel the dialog box, but underneath it is still dealing with the error. You should remove the messages section if you have nothing to add there, or create your messages as empty functions.